# Applications not staying in the correct display/workspace after monitor turns off

Tags: display, spaces

The setup has three displays (the mbp display and two extra ones), and multiple workspaces per display.

Whenever the machine goes idle for a while, the extra displays turn off, and the applications are shuffled.

Is there a way to keep the applications in the correct display/workspace?

The OS being used is Monterey 12.1

Answer (score 0):

Prevent the external display from switching off completely.
In standby it should maintain its connection. If actually 'off' then the Mac is making the correct response by moving off-screeen windows back on-screen. It cannot know if you will ever connect a second display again, so it must play safe, or your windows will be 'lost forver'.

This may be a setting in the display's OSD. You'll have to check the manual for specifics.

Comment: Sounds like something worth checking, will verify the configuration for the monitors and also the battery configuration for the macbook to avoid shutting them down, thanks!